# Encoding in CSV file not able to handle special character

Tags: c#, system.io.file

I have a CSV with the below content.

`1001,01 ░ - 02 Room,India,0`

And below is my code:

```
string row = "1001,01 ░ - 02 Room,India,0"
File.WriteAllText("MyCsv.csv", row);
```

It successfully creates MyCsv.csv, When I open this file with notepad this is what is see:

[image]

But when i open it with excel, this is what i see:

[image]

So basically "01 ░  - 02 Room" gets converted to "01 â–‘ - 02 Room" on opening with excel.

How to avoid this conversion? I want to see "01 ░  - 02 Room" on excel also.

Comment: The problem is how u open the file in Excel. Read this https://selzy.com/en/support/contact-lists/import-contact/charset-utf-8/

Comment: CSV isn't an Excel format. It's just a text file. When you double-click on that text file Excel will start and open it using the default encoding, the one matching the user's locale. In this case it seems the file is saved as UTF8 which almost certainly doesn't match the user's locale

Comment: Excel can detect Unicode files if a Byte-Order-Mark (BOM) is present. Normally UTF8 files don't have a BOM for .... compatibility reasons, which means no application, not even Excel, can detect them unless they read the entire file looking for byte sequences that only exist in UTF8. Thus causing *different* compatibility problems

Comment: Try using `File.WriteAllText("MyCsv.csv", row,Encoding.UTF8);` to generate a UTF8 file *with* a BOM that can be recognized by other applications, including Excel

Comment: Please please please, use a proper CSV formatter.  The encoding of both the file format and the data format will then be correct.  CSV has several gotcha's and isn't just a matter of writing strings.

Comment: I used CsvHelper nuget package. same issue

Answer (score 0):

`File.WriteAllText("MyCsv.csv", row,Encoding.UTF8);` resolved the issue